# WPF talking to secured web api using AutoRest

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger, azure-active-directory, autorest

I just can't seem to get anywhere with this.
I have a web api running fine, with a wpf application using the api via AutoRest.
The api has been uploaded to Azure (App Services)
I now want to lock down the api, so users log in via Active Directory. Again, all users are currently there.

```
RestCredentials = new TokenCredentials(tokenAuthResult.AccessToken);
```

Using the RestCredentials I pass in the credentials as type

```
ServiceClientCredentials

using (var db = new BuxtedAPI(Model.Helpers.Credentials.RestCredentials))
            {
                var res = db.GetComboList();
                ComboValueList = new ObservableCollection<ComboValue>(res);
                return ComboValueList;
            }
```

I can see on the log in Azure that the user successfully logs in.
But the system just dies with
Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'
No more feedback at all.
Just to note, I am using swagger also here.
I am assuming that the BuxtedAPI call that passing the credentials should pass through the bearer token for the api call to authorise.
I have set nothing else on on webapi code base, no [AUTHORIZED] or anything.
Any chance anyone can help me along here.
Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else gets in this situation.
The process required Resource Id to be the web app and the clientid to be the native app id.
Scott